# Setup a count down based on a time

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know how to setup a count down based on a time.. for example its 6pm and there is a time like 11PM, how would I have a countdown that I click a button no timer, that shows me you have 5 hours left etc.

```
Dim myTime As String = "7AM"
Dim date1 As DateTime = Date.Now
Dim date2 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Now.Date.ToLongDateString & " " & myTime)
Dim ts As New TimeSpan
ts = date2 - date1
TextBox.Text = ts.Hours & ":" & ts.Minutes & ":" & ts.Seconds
```

Comment: have you tried subtracting? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got it right, do you want to get the remaining time by clicking a button? which also means that you have to click it *everytime* for it to update?

```
Dim myTime As String = "7AM"
Dim date1 As DateTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt, dd MMMM yyyy")
Dim date2 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Now.Date.ToLongDateString & " " & myTime)

Dim ts As New TimeSpan
If date2 < date1 Then
    date2 = date2.AddDays(1)
End If
ts = date2 - date1


MsgBox(ts.Hours & ":" & ts.Minutes & ":" & ts.Seconds)
```

That would return a time with 16:30:00 with `hh:mm:ss` format.

Comment: the time format that I need help is like 11PM or 4:15PM so how to I make that conversion ?

Comment: you can do it by setting a format to a `datetime` variable. example: `Date.Now.ToString("t")`

Comment: i mean like I have Date.now and from a string I get 11:PM so how do I convert that '11PM' so that it works with the countdown ? like Date.Now.AddHours("11:30PM")

Comment: convert it to what? convert it to `datetime` ? do it like this 
`Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Now.Date.ToLongDateString & " " & "11PM")`

Comment: I'm quite confused now with what you want to achieve, can you give me an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: the person will select a time but there are only two choices 4:15PM 11:30PM.. I just want them to see a time remaining for them when they click a button, that's all

Comment: if the time now is 11:00PM, and I selected 11:30PM, the output should be 00:30:00 (hh:mm:ss) ? Is that what you want? :)

Comment: exactly, when I set for example "7AM" and lets say right now its 11 pm it just get out of whack... see sample source i posted

Comment: close but not yet, right now its 12:12AM here so for example the "7AM" shows me "18:46" im just a 7hrs away from 7am not 18.. and when I use "12:10AM" it shows me like 11hr but its more like almost 24hrs.. see what i mean ?

Comment: Now this is correct. you can also use timespan format `ts.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have updated the code. :) please also see @bansi's comment it would help you create a custom format for the `timespan`